# Volley not working, Android

Tags: android, sql, database, android-volley

I am building an android app and I am trying to send basic info on a phpmyadmin DB. I wrote a script (working, tested it with postman) and I used volley in my andorid app to send params to script. Here is my code.

```
   public class Info extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText e_mail, age, group_size;
    Button next;
    static final String insertURL = "http://www.studenti.famnit.upr.si/~89161009/IGIPAN/insertUser.php";
    static final String insertGroupURL = "http://www.studenti.famnit.upr.si/~89161009/IGIPAN/insertGroupUser.php";
    String id_user;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.info);

        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);

        e_mail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.e_mail);
        age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);
        group_size = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.group_size);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        id_user = intent.getStringExtra("id");

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                insertUser();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationSearch.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
    public void insertUser() {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d("", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> parametar = new HashMap<String, String>();
                parametar.put("id_user", id_user);
                parametar.put("age", String.valueOf(age.getText()));
                parametar.put("email", String.valueOf(e_mail.getText()));
                return parametar;

            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't get any errors. And I did a previous project that was very similar, and did it exactly like this and it worked. Now I can't figure out why it won't work.

Every answer is appreciated. Thank you!

*EDIT*
My script is:

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
        require 'connection.php';
        insertUser();
    }

    function insertUser(){
        global $connect;
        $id_user = $_POST["id_user"];
        $age = $_POST["age"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];

        $query = "INSERT INTO user ( id_user, age, email)
                    VALUES ( '$id_user', '$age', '$email');";
        mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connect));

        mysqli_close($connect);
    }

?>
```

Comment: If you are not getting any error in android. Plz add log in 
public void onResponse(String response) and see what is the response you are getting .

Comment: Thank you Nabil Mohanmed Nalakath! 
I am a goddamn idiot. The problem was that I used uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString(); to generate  a id. UUID is 36 of length, and i my table ID was only 35 length. So I got value to long for column error when I used the log in onResponse! 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to Nabil Mohammed Nalakath's suggestion to use log in onResponse(). Which gave me an value to long for column error.
Since I used `uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();` i got an id of length 36 and in my table i only set varchar(35). So I changed that and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I think whenever you get success response then you want to open LocationSearch screen for that you need to keep this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationSearch.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Inside onResponse() method and there you need to check have you got success response or not.If success then above code should be executed.

I think you should use **requestQueue.enque(request);**

Comment: Thank for your answer! I'll take your advice on the LocationSearch.class Intent. But I still can't insert a new user on my db. And requestQueue.enque(request) just gives me a syntax error.

Comment: @sameer He is not using singleton class i guess. So requestQueue.enque(request); is not necessary is his case.

Answer (score 0):

Its important to configure AndroidMenifest.xml file

by

and

```
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Comment: I think you missed a code snippet or something after the word "by".

Comment: oh its uses permission < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> and < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />